# SignalR scaleout iwith windows server service bus (not Azure service bus)

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

Can somebody suggest how to do SignalR scaleout using Windows server service bus 2 as messaging backplane (pl not this is not Azure service bus) in an Asp.net application.

After adding the following line, the run time error comes as "Network Error 500 for /signalr/hubs" :

File: Global.ascx.cs
Method: Application_Start()

Line: GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(svcBusConnectionString, MyChatApplication");

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot, enable server logging like in this [web.config](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/release/samples/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Samples/Web.config) file. Then, start your server and read the log file contents. You could also debug and see what exceptions are thrown.